# How to mute the android app using toggle button in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am using toggle button for mute and unmute the app sounds .When mute button is pressed I want to mute all the sounds in app.I am using media player for playing sounds .How to mute and unmute the media player using toggle button.

Here is my code ,

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tone_uyir_mei_ezhuthukal);
                mediaPlayer.start();




toggleButton=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);                               
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                   result.append(toggleButton.getText());                        
                   Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, result.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                   if (result.equals("volume")) {

                }else {

                }

            }
        });
```

I did not know how to proceed .Need help to mute and unmute the app using this toggle button

Comment: How about declaring a boolean variable, setting it with the ToggleButton, and only playing sounds if it's true.

Comment: take the value of toogle button as `true` or `false`. Then check that value and accordingly write code  whether to play sound or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 AudioManager  amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

 if(IsAudioOn){
            IsAudioOn = false;
            amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false); // for unmute

        }else{
            IsAudioOn = true;
            amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);  //for mute
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow ! In the future, please explain your answer and your code